# I need help installing Steam on my Chromebook thru Wine

Tags: wine, steam

I successfully installed Crouton and Wine on my Toshiba Chromebook 2. I downloaded Steam `.deb` file from the website and tried to install it but I keep getting this error message:

> Only one software management tool is allowed to run at the same time. Please close the application.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: You have synaptic open / are updating / are installing via the software center / are running `apt-get` / are running `pip` / are running `yum`. Close whatever else is using the install files and try again.

Comment: Restarting your system should help.

Comment: OIC  Yes, even straight ubuntu objects to having any two software managers open and active at once such as the software center and Synaptic, or even the software center and the update manager.  You merely need to close other software management applications which are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

download wine, open winetricks, under "install an app" mark steam ond click OK. This will install steam, Microsoft core fonts, and a bunch of other dependencies of windows steam